# The ignite is suspended during startup

Tags: ignite

Ignite keeps waiting when it starts,

```
"fm.ignite.monitor-69-1" #285 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=35865.92ms elapsed=83153.67s tid=0x000055a415a850e0 nid=0x17f1c in Object.wait() [0x00007f3cc5fd3000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.joinTopology(ServerImpl.java:1186)
    - locked <0x00000006f3b3f140> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.spiStart(ServerImpl.java:472)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.spiStart(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:2210)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:278)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager.start(GridDiscoveryManager.java:1089)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1766)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1147)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1799)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1721)
    - locked <0x00000006924b2580> (a org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1160)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:656)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:578)
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:328)
    at com.huawei.cloudsop.ignite.IgniteManager.start(IgniteManager.java:56)
    at com.huawei.iemp.fmdataservice.monitor.ignite.AlarmIgnite.getOrCreateCache(AlarmIgnite.java:115)
    at com.huawei.iemp.fmdataservice.monitor.ignite.dao.CurrentAlarmDaoImpl.startIgnite(CurrentAlarmDaoImpl.java:130)
    at com.huawei.iemp.fmdataservice.monitor.ignite.dao.IgniteMonitorTask.reStartIgnite(IgniteMonitorTask.java:75)
    at com.huawei.iemp.fmdataservice.monitor.ignite.dao.IgniteMonitorTask.run(IgniteMonitorTask.java:60)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Comment: When a node throws the cache is stopped exception, the service invokes ignite.close() and IgniteCache#close, and then ignite.start again.    is this OK?

Comment: Well, first of all this post is poorly formed, I can't see a question in fact. Please edit the post to make it actionable. In order to understand what's going I need a full thread dump (one particular stack is not enough) and maybe some logs from the startup routine. Speaking about closing an ignite instance after the "cache is stopped exception" - it doesn't make to much sense, don't mix the concepts of an instance and a cache.